# React Native Expo preload Assets / Images : How to import them?

Tags: react-native, expo

Im trying to preload images as otherwise there is a second delay when rendering them. Im not sure How to import the preloaded images? The way I am doing it now, there is still a delay. Thanks!!

```
    export default function App() {
    const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function prepare() {
            try {
                await Promise.all([
                    Font.loadAsync({
                        'MontserratReg': MontserratReg,
                        ...
                    }),
                    Asset.loadAsync([
                        require('../assets/images/logo.jpeg')
                    ])
                ]);
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn(e);
            } finally {
                setAppIsReady(true);
            }
        }
        prepare();
    }, []);
...

    return (
        <>
        ...
        </>
    );
};
```

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
...
   return (
     <ImageBackground
         source={require('../../assets/images/logo.jpeg')}
         resizeMode="cover"
     </ImageBackground>
   )
}
```